# LXD unprivileged container creation error? [LXD, Raspberry Pi3B]

Tags: ubuntu, arm, raspberry-pi3, lxc, lxd

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (kernel version 4.4.38-v7+) on Raspberry Pi 3B. I'm experimenting on using LXD but being new to virtualization, I am stumped with creating an unprivileged container.

These are the installation steps I followed:

```
> sudo apt install lxd
> sudo lxd init
    Do you want to configure a new storage pool (yes/no) [default=yes]? yes
    Name of the storage backend to use (dir or zfs) [default=dir]: dir
    Would you like LXD to be available over the network (yes/no) [default=no]? no
    Do you want to configure the LXD bridge (yes/no) [default=yes]? yes
    Would you like to setup a network bridge for LXD containers now? no
    Do you want to use an existing bridge? yes
    Bridge interface name:  br0
> reboot
> sudo lxc launch ubuntu:xenial/armhf ct01
```

However, the output of the last command produces an error:

```
error: Failed container creation:
    - https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases: LXD doesn't have a uid/gid allocation. In this mode, only privileged containers are supported.
```

These are the contents of my subuid and subgid files:

```
> cat /etc/subuid
ubuntupi:165536:65536
lxd:231072:65536
root:231072:65536
> cat /etc/subgid
ubuntupi:165536:65536
lxd:231072:65536
root:231072:65536
```

I tried changing `lxd` and `root` to `100000:65536` but the results are still the same. I have read some references regarding uid/gid allocation like [this](https://stgraber.org/2017/06/15/custom-user-mappings-in-lxd-containers/) and other threads as well but I still can't figure out a way to go about this. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? How can I create unprivileged containers?

Comment: Did you find out in the end? I'm having a very similar problem.